# Wordpress: custom_post_type image upload

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone help me to add a field for image uploading.Here is my current code!

```
    add_action('init', 'pictures_portofolio');

function pictures_portofolio() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __('Bilder'),
        'singular_label' => __('Bilder'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array(false)
    );

    register_post_type( 'Bilder' , $args );
}


add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
add_action('save_post', 'save_the_post');

function admin_init(){
    register_taxonomy("catalog", array("product"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Kategorien", "singular_label" => "Kategorien", "rewrite" => true));  

}


function save_the_post(){
    global $post;
    //update_post_meta($post->ID, "price", $_POST["price"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting:

```
'supports' => array('thumbnail')
```

... And your theme should support thumbnails too; place this in your theme's functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'Bilder' ) );
```

Hope it helps!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support

Comment: I want to be able to upload multiple images at the same time